# Are the dangers of Trophy Rush also beneficial?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In Super Smash Bros. for Wii U, there is a Trophy Rush mode which features the following dangers:

- An electric ball falls if you stand in the same place for too long
- A bomb block will explode after a time
- Engine exhaust blocks will perform a burn after a time

In addition to hurting and knocking around your character, these dangers also destroy blocks. Does this make these dangers also beneficial?

Do the blocks destroyed by these dangers...

1. add to your points?
2. contribute to your fever?
3. count toward your chain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stuff broken by hazards does give you points, but only half as normal, and without the chain multiplier. It doesn't contribute to your fever or chain.

[Source](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Trophy_Rush)